# Titlesec: \ifthesection command issue with biblatex refsegment

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to set my page style  and `biblatex` to print a cumulative bibliography subdivided by chapter. There seems to be some problem with the `\ifthesection` command because in the following MWE the headers in the odd pages of the bibliography should say, for instance, "References Chapter 1" but I'me getting "Bibliography" instead.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  
\newpagestyle{main}[\scshape]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}
  {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}
\newpagestyle{special}[\scshape]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\sectiontitle}{\chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\mainmatter}{\pagestyle{main}}
\appto{\backmatter}{\pagestyle{special}}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{\chapter{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbib}[\refname\space\chaptername\space
  \ref*{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}%
  \section{#1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\section{Baz} 
\lipsum
\nocite{*}
\chapter{Bar}
\nocite{*}

\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbib]

\end{document}
```

One workaround is to define a new pagestyle that doesn't use the `\ifthesection` command and do the following in the preamble:

```
\newpagestyle{bibatend}[\scshape]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitle]
  {\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
}
\appto{\backmatter}{\pagestyle{bibatend}}
```

However I would like to use the pagestyle `special` in the backmatter (because I have also an index that doesn't have sections and therefore the heading should always be the chapter title). So my question is: why is the `\ifthesection` command not working properly?

Comment: `titlesec` isn't compatible with `refsegment=chapter`. The option setting has biblatex patch low-level chapter commands. `titlesec` ignores these; it redefines the user-level `\chapter` command.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks, I didn't know that. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titlesec` package isn't compatible with any of the `biblatex` `refsegment` or `refsection` option settings. `biblatex` patches the low-level section/chapter commands. `titlesec` ignores all of these changes because it redefines the user-level section/chapter commands.

To workaround this you should omit the `refsegment=chapter` setting and create reference segments manually with:

```
\chapter{<title>}
\begin{refsegment}
...
\end{refsegment}
```